# XCode - Iphone project cannot run on iphone simulator?

Tags: iphone, xcode, target, targets

Something happened to my XCode Project.

On top left side of XCode 4 where you can specify what device/simulator you want to run your app on it does not show any iphone/ipad related target. It shows "My Mac 64-bit"

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: It's “Xcode”, not Xcode; “iPhone”, not “Iphone”. You’d have to try to get this stuff wrong, seriously.

Comment: @Jonathan: Lol. Even your correction to his incorrect posting is incorrect. It's "Xcode", not "Xcode"? Fail.

Comment: Wow, that's hilarious! I feel terrible… :) Suppose my phone autocorrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart XCode, see how you go.

Often when I use git to pull changes to the XCode4 project file the list in the top seems to lose it's place. Restarting fixes that issue very time for me. Totally annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I  figured it out. I had to edit the scheme (Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme...), and for some reason no executable was selected. I chose my app, saved and now I have my simulator and device options back.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is here:
[Xcode iOS project only shows "My Mac 64-bit" but not simulator or device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377970/xcode-ios-project-only-shows-my-mac-64-bit-but-not-simulator-or-device)

It's the answer posted my Mike Reining which says:
Right-click on the xcodeproj file and select "show package contents." Now delete everything inside the xcuserdata folder. Voila.

Make a backup copy of the xcuserdata folder before you delete it.