# Xcode iOS project only shows "My Mac 64-bit" but not simulator or device

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

This just started happening that my iOS project is only showing "My Mac 64-bit" rather than the Simulator or my iPhone to build to.  I have no idea why this is happening.  I do not think that I have changed anything.

[image]

I have my project set to iOS 5 as the base SDK, but no matter what I do it seems to never show my any other options to build for.  I have restarted Xcode a few times, and still no luck.

Why is the happening?

**Xcode 4.2, Build 4D199**

Answer (score 406, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to edit the scheme (Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme...), and for some reason no executable was selected. I chose my app, saved and now I have my simulator and device options back.

Comment: In my case, I have no executale selected and it runs fine... After I fix the **Base SDK** (under Build Settings) which was oddly wrongly set to "iphoneos" rather than "iOS 5.0" as it should and as it was before.

Comment: Had you recently changed the name of the XCode project (.xcodeproj) file? I've had this happen to me before too. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: @PaulShapiro Yeah, you know I might have changed the name before then, can't remember!

Comment: In my case executable is selected but still that mac scheme is coming.

Comment: FYI, I had this problem and like Paul, it happened just after I changed the name of my xcodeproj file.

Comment: where is executable button?

Comment: if you change the name of the compiled product, it will cause this problem.

Comment: In my case, this occurred after run `pod install` and opened newly created `.xcworkspace`.

Comment: I had to delete the user data from my `xcworkspace` as it was corrupted and xcode wouldn't open my project, that's when this occurred for me

Comment: I wish I could up vote this each time I have to go find it again. :-)

Comment: Where do you find "Product>Scheme>Edit Scheme" ????  Would be great if reader knew what that even meant.

Comment: @JohnPitts Product is one of the main top menus in Xcode.

Answer (score 88):

Here is how I solved this problem.  Right-click on the xcodeproj file and select "show package contents."  Now delete everything inside the xcuserdata folder.

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem after I renamed my xcodeproj file.

Comment: This answer assumes that the Xcode defaults are in place - i.e. the schemes you're using are not 'Shared' and you have 'Autocreate schemes' checked. For projects shared with a team you will often find one or both of these defaults disabled as they are user-centric (not collaborative).

Comment: This is not correct way to do. Accepted answer is accurate.

Comment: Yes -- a good idea to add .gitignore file at goo.gl/Oy5o6H to avoid story xcuserdata in git repo.

Comment: solved for me thanks, but i had to delete the shared data inside not the user data

Answer (score 41):

This is basically happen, when you change your project name or something like that. The solution is, you have to select the right "`Scheme`" for your project. Here is the solution :

After open your project :

1. `Go to "Product" from upper menu`
2. `Select "Scheme" from the list`
3. `Then select "Manage Scheme"`
4. `Now no matter your "Project Name" is listed here or not just click on "Autocreate Schemes Now" from the upper-right side of the window`.
5. `Press "ok", now your project rebuild and you can find the "Simulator List" on the top`.

Hope this help you guys.

Answer (score 40):

Had the same problem.

None of the above solutions worked. In the end, I clicked on "Manage Schemes" and then "Autocreate Schemes Now". Then select the new scheme in Xcode. Now you will get back all device/simulator options.

This might be a bit nuclear option if you are midway through the project. My problem happened as I was starting on a new project and renamed the project. In this scenario, only autocreating a new scheme seemed to work.

Comment: Hi @Anshu, then there'll be an old scheme for the old name, do you know to remove it?

Comment: @congliu The old scheme gets replaced by the new scheme. In case you are using version control like SVN, you will see the old scheme marked as "to be deleted upon commit" in your SVN client.

Comment: right answer in my case, choosing an executable was not an option since I was dealing with an extension.

Comment: Good Answer :) Thanks +1

Answer (score 19):

There are different solution to this problem. Two approaches that I have used are below :

1. Right-click on xcodeproj file. Select "show package contents".
   Now, delete everything inside the xcuserdata folder.
2. Select "Edit Schema". Executable section will have "none" in Info tab of window.
   Now select "ProjectName.app".

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: really helped me

Answer (score 11):

Often times this can happen when some files change without xcode's blessing. As in when switching between version control branches. Usually restarting Xcode fixes that problem.

Comment: Yeah, I had read that. But restarting in my case never helped.

Answer (score 9):

None of the suggestions here worked for me, but what did was clicking the project in the sidebar, then under "iOS Application Target", toggle "Devices".

I was set to 'iPad'. I changed it to 'Universal' then back to 'iPad' and the Scheme corrected itself.

If it makes a difference, this is on a PhoneGap/Cordova project.

Comment: If the deployment target is higher than your phone (i.e. running on a developer's preview Xcode then switching back) then this process changes the deployment target which causes the message to disappear! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If you are seeing this problem after you renamed your project, the actual issue is that the scheme has a container defined that refers to your old project name. You have to edit your scheme file also in a text editor and replace all the instances of the old project name with your new project name.

You've got to go through all the sub files in the project folder and replace the name of the old project with the new one to fix this issue. All the other work arounds listed in the other answers are just ways to force Xcode to do this for you.

Answer (score 7):

If nothing above work then click project from side bar as shown in image  at top then go to PROJECT then Build Settings then under Architectures change Supported Platforms from OSX to iOS.

Hope it will helps!

[image]

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me! Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Close Xcode entirely (Command + Q) and **install the additional component** solved the issue for me.

Comment: This worked for me when nothing else did. I restarted my computer as well

Answer (score 6):

I got this issue when i created a project with Xcode 4.5 (iOS SDK 6) and opened it later with Xcode 4.2 (iOS SDK < 6). I solved this problem, Select target->Summary, under Deployment target, i set it to 5.0:

[image]

Xcode 4.2 doesn't support iOS SDK 6.0, so i need to downgrade the deployment target, then i got my device in the scheme. Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 3):

Select Edit Schema, you'll be having None in "Executeable", select your .app instead from the drop down menu, Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Hi I got that issue a project I got it from a colleges.
I have solved it by Creating a "New Scheme" with project name.

Thanx,

Answer (score 3):

Generally sample codes downloaded has such issue. These can be changed by changing Base SDK to Latest iOS from 'Build Setting' tab of your Project.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem, and here is how i fixed it.

In "build Settings" change the "Supported Platforms" from "iphoneos" to "iOS". I don't know why, but it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Automatic settings validation solved this issue for me. ("Validate Settings" button)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by setting the deployment target version to a lower or same version  that the Xcode (iOS SDK) supports.

Answer (score 1):

in my case i had to change base SDK in project -> Build Settingd to latest ios sdk

Answer (score 0):

I tried every suggested solution I could find on stackoverflow for this problem.

Eventually, I **deleted the Xcode app and downloaded it again** from the App Store. After installation, the simulators were back.