# Xcode scheme changed automatically

Tags: xcode

Yesterday it was working and showing me option for building on **Device**, **iphone simulator** and **ipad simulator** but today it showing only for mac.
Please see this image:-[image]

edit:-Using Xcode 4.2 for lion
how can i get the build option for device and simulator and for ipad back.

Comment: What image? No link provided!

Comment: Found it fixed by restarting the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ! /dont know which version of Xcode you are running)

In xCode (with your project open), under SCM, select "Configure SCM For This Project..."

- Under "General", "Project Format:" select Xcode 3.2 -compatible
- Under "General", press "Rebuild Code Sense Index"
- Under "Build", "Architectures", "Base SDK" Select "iOS Device 4.1" (my Iphone was running 4.1, this might look different on your system?)
- Close the window, and in the upper-left corner, select "Device" and press "Build and Run"..

Comment: To open the General pane, choose Xcode > Preferences and click General.

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377970/xcode-ios-project-only-shows-my-mac-64-bit-but-not-simulator-or-device

Comment: Answer found here! Seems to be te same problem.

Comment: For me it changed to this new mac scheme.Please come in chat.

Comment: I found it fixed , i just restarted the system.