# Renamed iOS App id and now it says the schema is My Mac 64 bit?

Tags: ios, xcode

I decided to rename my iOS app by changing the bundle name and now xcode says the schema is "My Mac 64 bit"?

Does anyone have any clue on how to fix this?

UPDATE: Duplicate of this

[Xcode iOS project only shows "My Mac 64-bit" but not simulator or device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377970/xcode-ios-project-only-shows-my-mac-64-bit-but-not-simulator-or-device)

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Check the Base SDK setting for your project and ensure it is one of the iOS rows selected.