# CocoaPods setting wrong platform

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I've started using CocoaPods in my project - great product. Except I'm having an issue where every time I do 'pod install' it changes the pods project's platform to Mac OS (my project is an iOS app). What gives? Here's my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'MagicalRecord', '~> 2.2'
pod 'YAML-Framework', '~> 0.0.2'
#pod 'NewRelicAgent', '~> 3.184'

link_with 'My App', 'My Other App'

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!
```

Comment: check this question it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377970/xcode-ios-project-only-shows-my-mac-64-bit-but-not-simulator-or-device

Comment: Sadly not - those settings are correct in the main project.